# Understanding ID3v2.3 Tag

Tags: tags, mp3

I have a ID3v2.3 frame header as below what does it mean?

```
TPE2 00 00 00 1b 00 00 01 ff fe.
```

I know `TPE2` is Frame ID for Artist(Shown in ASCII).

`00 00 00 1b` - Is frame length in bytes.

Then what does `00 00 01 ff fe` mean?

Answer (score 1):

First two bytes in `00 00 01 ff fe` , i.e., `00 00` are flags.

Next byte `01` tells the encoding schema. `01` is unicode.

`ff fe` indicates beginning of unicode string.

You can find more detailed info [here](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_frame_overview).